# Active Directory -> Dirsync -> Office 365 best way to change password for remote users

Tags: active-directory, password-management, office365

We have a company 90% remote users with no laptops. (on government computers that they can't install anything on like a vpn)

our company is moving to Active directory and Office 365 and the passwords are synced useing "dirsync"

The question Im trying to find an elegant way of having our remote users change there password if they are not going to be attached to the network over a extended period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I forgot I posted this up here

We went with a product called ADselfserve plus by zoho corp

http://www.manageengine.com/products/self-service-password/

I was pretty easy to setup my only issue with it is it doesnt see to like to start back up after a update/reboot

Comment: update, Product still works but customer service with these guys is the worst.

Answer (score 1):

The company I'm working with currently does this with the Citrix login page;  if the password has expired, it brings users to a password-reset page instead of the Citrix login.  There are a number of ways to do this with a webpage.  This one is a commercial product but makes it very easy to implement: http://www.netwrix.com/active_directory_password_reset_tool.html

Comment: I also found this one http://www.quest.com/password-manager/

Comment: While you're at it, check out the other free Quest tools, before Dell decides to take them away!

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same issue. Here are the options:

- Utilities on the market that do this (others have pointed out some options)
- use ADFS (i seem to remember that it presents an option to change passwords remotely)
- we wrote our own web utility (took a couple of hours)

But finally, at this stage, we are almost thinking of not syncing passwords anymore. The benefits of managing the users through AD will still exist, but the password for AD and O365 will no longer be in sync - after running almost 1500 users over the last 5 months, this seems to be the best way forward for us (though we still haven't completely decided yet).